# Quadratic (programming) Optimization : Multiply by scalar

Tags: r, regression, optimization

I have two - likely simple - questions that are bothering me, both related to quadratic programming:

**1).** 
There are two "standard" forms of the objective function I have found, differing by multiplication of negative 1.

In the R package `quadprog`, the objective function to be minimized is given as $-d^{T}b + \frac{1}{2}b^{T}Db$ and in [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) the objective is given as $d^{T}b + \frac{1}{2}b^{T}Db$. How can these be the same? It seems that one has been multiplied through by a negative 1 (which as I understand it would change from a min problem to a max problem.

**2).** Related to the first question, in the case of using `quadprog` for minimizing least squares, in order to get the objective function to match the standard form, it is necessary to multiply the objective by a positive 2. Does multiplication by a positive number not change the solution?

**EDIT:** I had the wrong sign for the Matlab objective function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The function $-d^Tb+\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$ where $D$ is symmetric and convex and thus has unique minimum. In general that is called standard quadratic programming form, but that doesn't really matter. The other function $d^Tb-\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$ is concave function which has unique maximum. It is easy to show that for, say, bounded function $f(x)$ from above the following holds:
$$\arg \max_x f=\arg \min_x -f$$

Using the identity above value $b_1^*$ where $-d^Tb+\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$ achieves minimum is the same as the value $b_2^*$ which achieves maximum at $d^Tb-\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$, that is $b_1^*=b_2^*$.

Programmatically it doesn't matter if you are minimizing $-d^Tb+\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$ or maximizing the other one. These are implementation-dependent details.

2) No it does not. $\forall \alpha>0$ if $x^*=\arg \max_x f(x)$, then $x^*=\arg \max_x \alpha f(x)$. This can be showed by contradiction.

**After question was edited.**

3) Function $f(b)=d^T b$ is a linear function thus it is both convex and concave. From optimization standpoint it means you can maximize or minimize it.
Nevertheless minimizer of $-d^Tb+\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$ will be different from 
$d^Tb+\frac{1}{2}b^T D b$, because there is additional quadratic term. Matlab implementation will find the one with plus sign. So if you are using different optimization software you will need to change $d\rightarrow-d$ to get the same result.

Comment: I follow your description for #1, but if you look at the link for matlab I provided, it also speaks of minimizing the function. The function it is minimizing if the negative of the "standard quadratic form". How does that align to the answer?

Comment: I couldn't find mention of standard form on the matlab webpage. Matlab implementation find minimum of a convex function which has plus sign near quadratic term. Can you be more specific about what is unclear?

Comment: My confusion was that the matlab objective function (which is also being minimized) is not the same as the objective for the standard form (quadprog). It differs by the sign of d^{T}b$. These are not the same functions are they?

Comment: I initially wrote that the matlab objective was the negative of the standard form, but that was my error - please forgive the confusion that caused.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is this also related to why the sign of the inequality constraint is opposite for Matlab (is it related to the -d)?

Comment: Sign of inequality is unrelated to the sign of $d$. The reason there exist these standard form is that you can equivalently transform any problem of some class (quadratic programming in this case) into standard form. If so, there is only need to write solver for standard forms. P.S. If the answer above was satisfiable, consider accepting it.

Comment: So, if using Matlab versus R, you just need to multiply the constraints by (-1) to make them "work" for the given solver?

Comment: Yes, multiplying by -1 should work.